# Unable to import Nifi Registry flows committed in Git repository

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I am using Nifi-1.9.2 and Nifi registry-0.5.0 configured with PostgreSql database and git persistence providers. If i create buckets and flows, it gets committed in git repo and the bucket, flow ids get stored in PostreSql database. But if i try to import those flows in Nifi, it is throwing error as:
"The Flow Registry with ID bdc91c38-0173-1000-1a47-8335e91b99a3 reports that no Flow exists with Bucket 5c6f139a-27a5-4b61-83bd-5be5d43b516e, Flow bfd917c4-13e2-4d4b-afdc-346c9af02cb3, Version 1". The bucket flows gets committed in GitHub repo and in my local repo as .yml and .snapshot files.
[git flows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUuxm.png)

I tried to import like this in Nifi:
[import in Nifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smLSp.png)

Error:
[error thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5xtl.png)

This is my configuration in providers.xml:

```
<!--
<flowPersistenceProvider>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.registry.provider.flow.FileSystemFlowPersistenceProvider</class>
    <property name="Flow Storage Directory">./flow_storage</property>
</flowPersistenceProvider>
-->

<flowPersistenceProvider>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.registry.provider.flow.git.GitFlowPersistenceProvider</class>
    <property name="Flow Storage Directory">./bucket_flows</property>
    <property name="Remote To Push">origin</property>
    <property name="Remote Access User"><my username></property>
    <property name="Remote Access Password"><access token></property>
</flowPersistenceProvider>
```

Configuration in nifi-registry.properties file for PostgreSql database:

```
nifi.registry.db.url=jdbc:postgresql://<hostname:port>/nifireg
nifi.registry.db.driver.class=org.postgresql.Driver
nifi.registry.db.driver.directory=/path/to/drivers
nifi.registry.db.username=nifireg
nifi.registry.db.password=nifireg
```

Can any one please guide me how to import flows committed in GitHub to Nifi canvas?

This is the error in Nifi registry logs:

```
2020-08-06 19:06:24,038 ERROR [NiFi Registry Web Server-56] 
o.a.n.r.web.mapper.ThrowableMapper An unexpected error has occurred: 
org.apache.nifi.registry.flow.FlowPersistenceException: Flow ID 3d25253c-abff-4f95-b590-60a11184c5ec version 1 was not found in bucket bucket1:33cd0e85-3470-4ada-b4e6-e9dfd073ae1d.. Returning Internal Server Error response.
org.apache.nifi.registry.flow.FlowPersistenceException: Flow ID 3d25253c-abff-4f95-b590-60a11184c5ec version 1 was not found in bucket bucket1:33cd0e85-3470-4ada-b4e6-e9dfd073ae1d.
at org.apache.nifi.registry.provider.flow.git.GitFlowPersistenceProvider.getFlowContent(GitFlowPersistenceProvider.java:186)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.service.RegistryService.getVersionedFlowSnapshot(RegistryService.java:784)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.service.RegistryService.getFlowSnapshot(RegistryService.java:769)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.service.RegistryService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$274de08.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$$Lambda$665/1886429281.proceedWithInvocation(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.service.RegistryService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c562e243.getFlowSnapshot(<generated>)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.web.api.BucketFlowResource.getFlowVersion(BucketFlowResource.java:468)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$$Lambda$605/1327408227.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.serviceImpl(ServletContainer.java:409)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:584)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:525)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.web.security.authorization.ResourceAuthorizationFilter.forwardRequestWithoutAuthorizationCheck(ResourceAuthorizationFilter.java:151)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.web.security.authorization.ResourceAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(ResourceAuthorizationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.web.security.authentication.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.web.security.authentication.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:427)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:321)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Error in Nifi logs:

```
ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroup Failed to synchronize StandardProcessGroup[identifier=c344fc07-0173-1000-cbaf-0e7f5dbcc400] with Flow Registry because could not retrieve version 1 of flow with identifier 3d25253c-abff-4f95-b590-60a11184c5ec in bucket 33cd0e85-3470-4ada-b4e6-e9dfd073ae1d
org.apache.nifi.registry.client.NiFiRegistryException: Error retrieving flow snapshot: An unexpected error has occurred. Please check the logs for additional details.
at org.apache.nifi.registry.client.impl.AbstractJerseyClient.executeAction(AbstractJerseyClient.java:85)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.client.impl.JerseyFlowSnapshotClient.get(JerseyFlowSnapshotClient.java:97)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.flow.RestBasedFlowRegistry.getFlowContents(RestBasedFlowRegistry.java:206)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.flow.RestBasedFlowRegistry.getFlowContents(RestBasedFlowRegistry.java:220)
at org.apache.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroup.synchronizeWithFlowRegistry(StandardProcessGroup.java:3277)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController$5.run(FlowController.java:823)
at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1098)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:883)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$1(JerseyInvocation.java:767)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$$Lambda$444/2078720360.call(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:414)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:765)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:428)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:324)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.client.impl.JerseyFlowSnapshotClient.lambda$get$1(JerseyFlowSnapshotClient.java:104)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.client.impl.JerseyFlowSnapshotClient$$Lambda$379/302253921.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.nifi.registry.client.impl.AbstractJerseyClient.executeAction(AbstractJerseyClient.java:71)
... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: That error message is probably masking the real error, can you see if there is anything else in nifi-app.log, nifi-user.log, or nifi-registry-app.log

Comment: I have attached the error logs in the question...please let me know the root cause of this error.